# How to update join table using sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, join, sql-update, exists

I've read many similar threads but still can't make it work.

I have 2 tables, "stores_bars" and "house_data" and I need to update part of their join to make this work that way:

```
UPDATE (
SELECT good_id FROM stores_bars
INNER JOIN house_data ON SID=ID
WHERE typ = 3 AND owner = ''
)
SET good_id = 0
;
```

but this throws an syntax error. Literally, the table "house_data" is over 5k rows, the second one is over 1k rows and the select itself has only 220 rows, which I need to assign "0" value to (from that select).

I tried with REPLACE INTO, but in this scenario couldn't SET good_id = 0 as another syntax. I've tried UPDATE FROM clause which as well didn't work:

```
UPDATE stores_bars FROM
INNER JOIN house_data ON SID=ID
WHERE typ = 3 AND owner = ''
)
SET good_id = 0
;
```

`SQL Error: near "FROM": syntax error` is the message.

Maybe it's easier that I think but just stuck on this?

**EDIT**

According to the syntax this should work:

```
UPDATE stores_bars 
SET good_id = 0
FROM stores_bars
INNER JOIN house_data ON SID=ID
WHERE typ = 3 AND owner = ''
;
```

but it doesn't. The error is `SQL Error: near "FROM": syntax error`. I dunno whether my sqlite is not up to date - don't know how to update it. There's some workaround for this and I'm searching for it.

**EDIT 2**

I've managed to find proper syntax:

```
UPDATE stores_bars 
SET good_id = NULL
WHERE SID IN
( SELECT good_id FROM stores_bars
INNER JOIN house_data ON SID=ID
WHERE typ = 3 AND owner = '' )
;
```

but while that inner query returns 219 results, the whole update got me that message:
`Query OK, 24 rows affected (0.22 sec)`.

Should be 219, shouldn't it??

Comment: You say you're using sqlite, but you tagged your question mysql. Can you please confirm which database you are using, and update the tag to be accurate? It's in your own interest to tag questions accurately, because it attracts the people who are best qualified to give you the answer.

Comment: the query indicate that [tag:sqlite] is the correct tag. i have never seen [tag:mysql] allows `from` in an `update` statement and the error message looks different.

Comment: Have you read the examples of `UPDATE...FROM` queries in the SQLite manual? It shows the correct syntax, and even discusses differences with Microsoft and MySQL. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Comment: @BagusTesa sorry for my mistake, just updated this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for [`UPDATE...FROM`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html#update_from) (requires version 3.33.0 of SQLite) is this:

```
UPDATE stores_bars 
SET good_id = 0
FROM house_data
WHERE SID = ID AND typ = 3 AND owner = '';
```

Although it is actually a join, there are no `JOIN` and `ON` clauses.

But, it is always better to use the tables' names/aliases as qualifiers in your code. Something like this (although I'm not sure in which table the columns belong):

```
UPDATE stores_bars AS s 
SET good_id = 0  -- the updated column should not be qualified with the table's alias
FROM house_data AS h
WHERE s.SID = h.ID AND h.typ = 3 AND h.owner = '';
```

For versions of SQLite prior to 3.33.0, use `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE stores_bars AS s 
SET good_id = 0  
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM house_data AS h
  WHERE s.SID = h.ID AND h.typ = 3 AND h.owner = ''
);
```

Comment: I get `SQL Error: near "FROM": syntax error` still there...

Comment: @Peter.k is you SQLite version at least 3.33.0?

Comment: I guess it's not but I'm unable to check the version in a manager I use. On the system it's probably up to date but I'm also working in that manager.

Comment: @Peter.k execute `select sqlite_version();` and you will get the version.

Comment: version is 3.7.10

Comment: @Peter.k your version is more than 11 years old. You need at least 3.33.0 for the UPDATE...FROM syntax to work.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I need to manage it, either the newer version or a query from second edit, which works but gets wrong results.

Comment: @Peter.k check my edited answer.

Comment: Yes, it's gonna work now but, in this version, without the fragment `AS s` but it's not important. Thank you.